# How to change the position of the QTableWidget itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

How can I change the position of a tableWidget? This method doesn't work:

```
self.tableWidget.move(100,100)
```

Tried some other methods like self.tableWidget.x and self.tableWidget.y but no luck

An screenshot of the table:
[image: An screenshot of the table]

And this is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
                      
#Main Window 
class App(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 
        self.title = 'PyQt5 - QTableWidget'
        self.left = 200
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 740
        self.height = 880
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title) 
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height) 
        self.createTable() 
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget) 
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show() 
   
    def createTable(self):
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget() 
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(8)  
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(8) 
        self.tableWidget.setFixedSize(700,700)
        self.tableWidget.move(100,100)
        
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True) 
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True) 
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    ex = App() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the position manually then you should **not use the layouts** but just pass the window as parent.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QHeaderView, QTableWidget, QWidget

# Main Window
class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "PyQt5 - QTableWidget"
        self.left = 200
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 740
        self.height = 880
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.createTable()

    def createTable(self):
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(8)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(8)
        self.tableWidget.setFixedSize(700, 700)
        self.tableWidget.move(100, 100)

        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you so much! now I can move the table freely. but the last column's size is not equal to the others as I mentioned in the picture. what should I do about it?

Comment: @Arash 1) To avoid unnecessary discussions please read [ask], [answer] and pass the [tour] that you were given when you created your account. 2) According to the SO rules, the post must contain a specific question and not a set of questions, since here the answers only answer a question, so I edit your post and delete everything about the other problem you had, so yes you want help in your other problem then create another post. 3) If you want help then first follow the rules, and to comply with them you must first read them